# wordpress 3.1+ - custom post types - single template - next and previous navigation links

Tags: wordpress, navigation, custom-post-type

I'm using wordpress 3.1

I got 3 types of custom types : videos, galleries and podcasts. They use the default taxonomy categories.

When viewing a single custom post let's say a video, the next_post_link() (or previous_post_link) function works as planed but it links only to the next or previous post from this custom post type.

How could I get it to display the next post from any post type? tried to search hours on google without finding anything relevant to this. Anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to remove the `post_type` clause from the SQL query used to retrieve the adjacent post. This can be done by hooking into the `get_next_post_where` and `get_previous_post_where` filters, although it's not ideal as the SQL query is passed as a single string.

```
add_filter('get_next_post_where', 'my_get_adjacent_post_where_filter');
add_filter('get_previous_post_where', 'my_get_adjacent_post_where_filter');
function my_get_adjacent_post_where_filter($sql) {
  return preg_replace("/ AND p.post_type = '[^']*'/", '', $sql);
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot, that pointed me in the right direction, now i'll just modify the function to limit the post_type, because now it gets everything even pages.

Comment: changed the last line to :
`return preg_replace("| AND p.post_type = '[^']*'|", " AND (p.post_type = 'post' OR p.post_type = 'podcast' OR p.post_type = 'video') ", $sql);`